# Modify a custom layer in Keras, after training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback, keras-layer, conv-neural-network

I've a created a CNN with a customized layers that takes in some values. I would like to modify those values using Callback on validation phase. How can I proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which variables are you talking about? Can you give an example?